# Basic :nth-child cunfusion

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set different width for the overlay of my progress bars. But for some reason the :nth-child selector isn't working the way I hoped it would, haha. I suspect that it might have something to do with the parent-child relation in CSS, by I'm still perplexed as to what I'm overlooking.

Could someone with a fresh set of eyes take a look, and explain to me what I'm missing/doing wrong? Also, sorry if this is a copy of an exisiting thread, haven't been able to find an answert for my exact question!!

Here's the mockup I have some far:

```css
.progress {
    height: 300px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.progress-bar-overlay {
    height: 35px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #00FFA5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

/* Why isn't the width being set to 80%? */

.progress-bar-overlayy:nth-child(3) {
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
 

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `.progress-bar:nth-child(3) .progress-bar-overlay` work?

Comment: `progress-bar-overlayy` you wrote 2 **y**.

Comment: each `.progress-bar-overlay` is viewed as having no siblings because they are separated into different parent divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:nth-child(3)` will look at the third child of its direct parent, and because each progress-bar only has one child, you will never get this.

What you need to do is to say that you want `progress`'s third child (which is a `progress-bar`), and take its child, like this:

```
.progress-bar:nth-child(3) .progress-bar-overlay {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my good man! Makes sense all of the sudden! Appreciate you!